# (Google Sheets) How do I eliminate drop down options if that option has been chosen? Follow up

Tags: arrays, validation, google-sheets, dropdown

A previous user had posed this question:

[(Google Sheets) How to remove certain dropdown options after a certain number of cells with said option is met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75295565/google-sheets-how-to-remove-certain-dropdown-options-after-a-certain-number-of)

The God of Biscuits answered with Array code that I have been toying with.

> Here's a toy example you may be able to adapt to your needs:
>
> 1.Create a list of options a,b,c,d,e in A1:E1 of Sheet1
>
> 2.Create a list of the limits for each option in A2:E2 (for instance 2,1,3,5,3)
>
> 3. Create a list of people Person1,Person2,Person3 in G2:G4
> 4. Apply data validation to H2:H4:
>
>    - Use criteria 'drop down (from a range)'
>    - Set the data range to =Sheet1!$A3:$E3 (only lock columns, not rows)
> 5. In A3 enter the following formula:
>
>    =lambda(people,choices,list,limits,
>    makearray(counta(people),counta(list),lambda(r,c,
>    if(index(choices,r)<>index(list,,c),if(countif(choices,index(list,,c))<index(limits,,c),index(list,,c),),index(list,,c)))))(
>    $G$2:$G$4,$H$2:$H$4,$A$1:$E$1,$A$2:$E$2)
>
> We are using MAKEARRAY to create a 2D array with the list of options on each line, however we are asking it to omit elements of the list from each line if they haven't already been selected AND a preset limit on the number of selections for that option has not been reached. Obviously in a 'real' example you would place the data range for validation in a separate sheet and probably hide and protect that sheet as well. You could also potentially use an array literal of strings rather than a cell range as the list of options in order to make the validation list formula completely self-contained.

Using their example how could you allow each Person to make 3 choices within the same limiting parameters?

Each student would have to choose 3 committees. And choices in the drop down list would disappear if other students had already chosen those committees and they had reached their max.

[Table with Each Person having 3 to choose 3 Activities from a drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIk3c.png)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Would you please edit the question to include sample data as well as one or more examples of a successful outcome. If the formula from the linked question is relevant, please include that  formula in the question too.

Comment: I attempted to add the relevant information. Apologies if it is clumsy.

Comment: Would you explain why the answer in the referenced topic doesn’t apply to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reworked the logic of my answer to the previous question (and tidied it up a bit as we now have access to `let` which we didn't have back then, plus I've embedded the choices and limits into the formula) to satisfy the additional requirement of multiple choices per person.

So, given your table with a list of people in G2:G5 and Choice1/2/3 as a header in H1:J1:

1. Apply data validation to H2:J5:

   - Use criteria 'drop down (from a range)'
   - Set the data range to =Sheet1!$A1:$E1 (only lock columns, not rows)
2. In A1 enter the following formula:

```
=arrayformula(let(
people,tocol(G2:G,1),
choices,offset(H2,,,counta(people),3),
list,{"Activity A","Activity B","Activity C","Activity D","Activity E"},
limits,{2,2,2,2,2},
choicesperperson,byrow(choices,lambda(chosen,if(ifna(match(list,chosen,0)),,list))),
underlimit,(counta(people)-countif(choicesperperson,list))<limits,
if(underlimit,choicesperperson,)))
```

As per last time, in a 'real' example you should place the data range for validation in a separate sheet and probably hide and protect that sheet as well. I've set the limit to each activity to 2 but you can adjust this as needed by modifying the values in the *limits* array.

Comment: I think it got a little funky because the limits used to be in A2:E2. So now Person 2 drop down is the numbers from the limits and not the Activities.  Should I be pasting the new formula into A2 instead?  Also this is amazing and I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: So it is not working for me I'll keep playing around but currently with the limits set to 2.  If person 1 picks activity A. Person 2 does not even have Activity A as an option. Also when person 1 goes to put in their second choice all options are available even if Activities have reached their limit.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo - formula should go in A1 (not A3 as originally stated). Make sure you have removed the choices and limits that were originally in A1:E1 and A2:E2 in my answer to the previous question - as I stated in this answer I have now embedded these into the formula itself.